# Type text on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 12.04

I've had Ubuntu 12.04 for a few weeks, and, as a first time Ubuntu user, I'm still oblivious to a lot of it's features. The one in question at the moment, when I type in text while I'm on my desktop, a little text box appears in the lower right corner.
What is this for?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457583/what-does-super-e-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box in the corner is a search box. As you type, it highlights an icon on your desktop that matches your search query. Pressing the up and down keys on your keyboard lets you cycle through the icons that match the query.

Comment: Thank you, I actually figured it out by myself a few minutes after I asked this question, but thanks for the effort anyway.